# How to make eclipse open the console automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can Eclipse be made to open the console automatically when a program is run? I can't seem to find the preference for it.

Ideally, the result would be similar to the console behaviour in NetBeans, where the console will open up automatically when a program is run.

How can this be achieved?

the settings under `console` only shows these options:

[image]

**Edit: Suggestion from Comment**
The option to open the console seems to be excluded, why?

[image]

Comment: @tbodt Eclipse has many more plugins and better android support so, respectfully, no..

Comment: You can use the "pin console" button to ensure it stays on top. Other than that, I thought the two checkboxes "show when program writes...." were supposed to handle that.

Comment: @ylun.za It's not an option, it's a window, like the Package Explorer and so on. Window>Show View>Console.

Comment: @derstrom8 okay thanks for that suggestion. Yea i thought so as well but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Aarowaim Yes i know that. However, i would like it to show up whenever a program runs, like in netbeans. If the console is closed, it doesn't come up again when something is run.

Comment: @ylun.za I believe the option you are looking for is in Preferences>Run/Debug>Perspectives>Open the associated perspective when launching

Comment: @derstrom8 Nevermind on my last comment. Yes the console does automatically show when a `System.out.print` is done but does not show if, for e.g., the program is asking for an input from a Scanner.

Comment: @Aarowaim Thanks for that last suggestion, check my next edit for details, eclipse isn't making any sense..

Comment: @ylun.za A perspective *contains* views; you have to choose a perspective that includes the console view. Use the 'Java' perspective, or make your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Preferences>Run/Debug>Perspectives and select `Java Application`. Then, go to the right side and change the run perspective to `Java`, or make your own perspective that includes the console window. Double check that "Open the associated perspective when launching" is set to "Always", or "prompt". I tested the settings below by running while in the debug perspective; it switched to the Java perspective automatically.

[image]

The console is a view; a smaller part of any perspective. Because the Java perspective includes the console view, conveniently placed below your code, using the Java perspective and setting it to launch automatically will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Windows→Run/Debug→Console and select both *Show when program writes to standard out* and *Show when program writes to standard error*

Then it will pop open the Console window regardless of whether you are in the Java or Debug perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is something being output to the console, Eclipse will open the Console automatically on running the program.  Try a simple test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("I'm in the console!");
}
```

Comment: Yes the console does automatically show when a System.out.print is done but does not show if, for e.g., the program is asking for an input from a Scanner.

Comment: Somehow my Eclipse no longer automatically shows the console no matter how you write to it. "Simple tests" like this do not work for me. @simpleuser's fix seems to work work me.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open eclipse
2. Open console window
3. Right click on console window-->Preferences-->Restore defaults-->Apply and close